# Hashing database acess passwords in R scripts

Tags: r, hash

I have some R scripts which rely on ODBC to retrieve data from a server database. Although this is shared within my team only, we wish to hash the database access password nevertheless.  Greatly appreciated if fellow users could share best approaches for doing so. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is [PKI](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PKI/PKI.pdf): store the password as vector encrypted through PKI.encrypt, with a key shared between team members, and then prompt the user to decrypt it which requires the key only your team has - when the script first runs. R is sort of slim on encryption/decryption packages; you basically have PKI and [digest](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/digest/index.html) which is asymetric, and that's it.